# How to fix titanium ERROR: Asset package include titanium.jar not found

Tags: android, titanium

Well, I have configured the emulator, the paths in the studio, everything seems to be ok, but i can't make it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is still an issue but certain version of titanium does not support Android build tools above a certain version like explained here:

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178514/

So you could check this and check if your titanium is up to date.